# Looping through an array to calculate relative error

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to get my program to run through four nested while loops to calculate the relative error of a user entered number by drawing from the array {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1/2, -1/3, -1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Here is an excerpt from this assignment:

"Consider the de Jager formula w^a x^b y^c z^d, where each of a, b, c, and d is one of the 17 numbers {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1/2, -1/3, -1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. The "charming theory" asserts that the de Jager formula with your four personal numbers can be used to approximate μ within a fraction of 1% relative error. For example, suppose you choose to approximate the mean distance from the earth to the moon in miles: μ = 238,900. And suppose you are an OSU sports fan, so your personal numbers are the number of wins in OSU's last national championship season (14; also the record for wins in a year by any college team), the seating capacity of Ohio Stadium (102,329), the year of Jesse Owens' four gold medals in Berlin (1936), and your jersey number when you played high school field hockey (13). Then the value of 14-5102329119361/2134 is about 239,103, which is within about 0.08% of μ.

Your job is to create a Java program that asks the user what constant μ should be approximated, and then asks in turn for each of the four personal numbers w, x, y, and z. The program should then calculate and report the values of the exponents a, b, c, and d that bring the de Jager formula as close as possible to μ, as well as the value of the formula waxbyczd and the relative error of the approximation to the nearest hundredth of one percent."

The code below is what I have so far. I realize it is not working in it's current state but I hope that I am at least on the right track with it. I am just not sure where to go from here or how to fix my nested loops. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am really struggling with how this should work. I also realize that for loops would be better for this kind of nested looping but I need to use while loops before I can use for.

```
import components.simplereader.SimpleReader;
import components.simplereader.SimpleReader1L;
import components.simplewriter.SimpleWriter;
import components.simplewriter.SimpleWriter1L;


public final class ABCDGuesser1 {


private ABCDGuesser1() {
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L();
    SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();

    out.print("Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: ");
    double mu = in.nextDouble();

    out.print("Enter four postitive numbers not equal to 1: ");
    double w = in.nextDouble();
    double x = in.nextDouble();
    double y = in.nextDouble();
    double z = in.nextDouble();

    int[] charm = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1 / 2, -1 / 3, -1 / 4, 0, 1 / 4,
            1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int a = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < charm.length) {
        a = charm[i];
        double max1 = (Math.pow(w, a));
        i++;

        int b = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < charm.length) {
            b = charm[j];
            double max2 = (Math.pow(x, b));
            j++;

            int c = 0;
            int k = 0;
            while (k < charm.length) {
                c = charm[k];
                double max3 = (Math.pow(y, c));
                k++;

                int d = 0;
                int n = 0;
                while (n < charm.length) {
                    d = charm[n];
                    double max4 = (Math.pow(z, d));
                    n++;
                }
                out.print(max1);
            }
        }
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Well for one you should work with a double[] as an int -1/2 or any fraction 1/4 would be rounded to be an int.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, have you learned about `for` loops? They would let you shorten your code a bit.

Comment: Sorry, but I refuse to look at any question that requires me to assume I am an OSU sports fan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. as mentioned by Invexity, double[] charm, not int[] charm
2. whilst looping, keep track of the bestEstimate

so code your code would be

```
package area51;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public final class ABCDGuesser1 {

    private ABCDGuesser1() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintStream out = System.out;
        //out.print("Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: ");
        double mu = 2.567;

        //out.print("Enter four postitive numbers not equal to 1: ");
        double w = 123.4;
        double x = 2.567;
        double y = 8.9;
        double z = 12.6;

        double[] charm = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1 / 2, -1 / 3, -1 / 4, 0, 1 / 4, 1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        double bestEstimate = 0;
        String bestIndexes = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < charm.length; i++) {
            double max1 = (Math.pow(w, charm[i]));
            for (int j = 0; j < charm.length; j++) {
                double max2 = (Math.pow(x, charm[j]));
                for (int k = 0; k < charm.length; k++) {
                    double max3 = (Math.pow(y, charm[k]));
                    for (int n = 0; n < charm.length; n++) {
                        double max4 = (Math.pow(z, charm[n]));
                        double currentEstimate = max1 * max2 * max3 * max4;
                        if (Math.abs(mu - currentEstimate) < Math.abs(mu - bestEstimate)) {
                            bestEstimate = currentEstimate;
                            bestIndexes = ""+i+","+j+","+k+","+n;
                        }
                    }
                    //out.print(max1);
                }
            }
        }
        out.println("Best Estimate = " + bestEstimate);
        out.println("Best Indexes = " + bestIndexes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how to properly use the bestEstimate value. For step 6 you show that I should subtract bestEstimate from mu, but if I never gave bestEstimate a value (other than 0) won't that be meaningless?  Also, for step 5 you say to have estimate = max1 * max2 * max3 * max4, but estimate was never declared. Do you mean to say currentEstimate there?

Comment: @Devasive I translated my answer into code and yes, when I said "estimate" I should have said "currentEstimate".

Comment: This is the output I am getting from running the program you have posted:Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: 238900
Enter four postitive number not equal to 1: 14
102329
1936
13
Best Estimate = 253104.94721879277Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Violation of: this is open
 at components.simplewriter.SimpleWriter1L.print(SourceFile:114)
 at ABCDGuesser1.main(ABCDGuesser1.java:90)                                 Do you have any idea why it is not running correctly? Also, sorry for the bad formatting here, I can't seem to add line breaks.

Comment: I fixed errors (yours and mine) and made it a bit more tidy. I hardcoded numbers so you can test with same as me. It worked for me with output: Best Estimate = 2.567
Best Indexes = 5,12,5,5

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I really appreciate it. I have just one more question which I will put into code.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Could you tell me why these two programs give different outputs? The only difference between them that I can see is that the first uses while loops with no method, while the second uses for loops and a main method. I don't want to change the for loop program anymore if I have to, I just want the while loop program's output to match that of the for loop one. The output for the first program is:

Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: 238900
Enter four postitive number not equal to 1: 14
102329
1936
13
Most appropriate exponents for w, x, y and z: 1 14 6 12
Best Estimate = 253104.94721879277
Relative error = 0.059459804180798555%
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Violation of: this is open
at components.simplewriter.SimpleWriter1L.println(SourceFile:177)
at ABCDGuesser1.main(ABCDGuesser1.java:93)

Second program:

Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: 238900
Enter four postitive number not equal to 1: 14
102329
1936
13
Most appropriate exponents for w, x, y and z: -4.0 2.0 1.0 -3.0
Best Estimate = 240193.14762851998
Relative error = 0.0054129243554624324
*/    


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L();
    SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();

    out.print("Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: ");
    double mu = in.nextDouble();

    out.print("Enter four postitive number not equal to 1: ");
    double w = in.nextDouble();
    double x = in.nextDouble();
    double y = in.nextDouble();
    double z = in.nextDouble();

    double[] charm = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1 / 2, -1 / 3, -1 / 4, 0,
            1 / 4, 1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double bestEstimate = 0;
    double a, b, c, d;
    double bestIndex1 = 0;
    double bestIndex2 = 0;
    double bestIndex3 = 0;
    double bestIndex4 = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < charm.length) {
        a = (Math.pow(w, charm[i]));
        i++;

        int j = 0;
        while (j < charm.length) {

            b = (Math.pow(x, charm[j]));
            j++;

            int k = 0;
            while (k < charm.length) {

                c = (Math.pow(y, charm[k]));
                k++;

                int n = 0;
                while (n < charm.length) {

                    d = (Math.pow(z, charm[n]));
                    double currentEstimate = a * b * c * d;

                    if (Math.abs(mu - currentEstimate) < Math.abs(mu
                            - bestEstimate)) {
                        bestEstimate = currentEstimate;
                        bestIndex1 = charm[i];
                        bestIndex2 = charm[j];
                        bestIndex3 = charm[k];
                        bestIndex4 = charm[n];
                    }
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
        double relError = Math.abs((mu - bestEstimate) / mu);
        out.println("Most appropriate exponents for w, x, y and z: "
                + bestIndex1 + " " + bestIndex2 + " " + bestIndex3 + " "
                + bestIndex4);

        out.println("Best Estimate = " + bestEstimate);

        out.println("Relative error = " + relError + "%");

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}






private static double relError(double constant, double fin) {
    double estimate = Math.abs((constant - fin) / constant);

    return estimate;
}

/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L();
    SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();

    out.print("Enter a positive real-valued universal physical or mathematical constant: ");
    double mu = in.nextDouble();

    out.print("Enter four postitive number not equal to 1: ");
    double w = in.nextDouble();
    double x = in.nextDouble();
    double y = in.nextDouble();
    double z = in.nextDouble();

    double[] charm = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1 / 2, -1 / 3, -1 / 4, 0,
            1 / 4, 1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double bestEstimate = 0;
    double bestIndex1 = 0;
    double bestIndex2 = 0;
    double bestIndex3 = 0;
    double bestIndex4 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < charm.length; i++) {
        double a = (Math.pow(w, charm[i]));
        for (int j = 0; j < charm.length; j++) {
            double b = (Math.pow(x, charm[j]));
            for (int k = 0; k < charm.length; k++) {
                double c = (Math.pow(y, charm[k]));
                for (int n = 0; n < charm.length; n++) {
                    double d = (Math.pow(z, charm[n]));
                    double currentEstimate = a * b * c * d;
                    if (Math.abs(mu - currentEstimate) < Math.abs(mu
                            - bestEstimate)) {
                        bestEstimate = currentEstimate;
                        bestIndex1 = charm[i];
                        bestIndex2 = charm[j];
                        bestIndex3 = charm[k];
                        bestIndex4 = charm[n];

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double error = relError(mu, bestEstimate);

    out.println("Most appropriate exponents for w, x, y and z: "
            + bestIndex1 + " " + bestIndex2 + " " + bestIndex3 + " "
            + bestIndex4);

    out.println("Best Estimate = " + bestEstimate);

    out.print("Relative error = ");
    out.println(error);

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: There is a difference in your logic between the "for" and "while" versions. The i,j,k are incremented before the next loop. In the "for" statements, i etc are updated after the internal loop. This will affect the indexes you print out but I am not sure why the actual answer is different. I have to head out now but will try and have another look tomorrow if it is still a problem.

Comment: I found my error. I had my output statements within my first while loop at the bottom. I fixed that and they are now both giving the same answers. Thanks again!